# How do group values in ranges in a column in R e.g 5-10?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to display data in a data frame such that it is in the form 5-10. Here is the sample data I have:

| count | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 0.3 |
| 5 | 0.5 |

I would like the output data to look like this

| count | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1-2 | 0.1 |
| 3-4 | 0.3 |
| 5 | 0.5 |

The count column values are of factor type.

Here is what I have so far but it is not working. I tried to compare two values at a time and then if the difference was not 1, then I wanted to output it as a character as 1-2:

```
count <- factor(c(1,1,3,5))
percentage <- c(0.1, 0.1,0.3,0.5)

info <- data.frame(count, percentage)
str(info)
hits <-as.numeric(as.character(info$count))
hits

for(i in hits){
  #print(i)
  if(hits[i+1] - hits[i] != 1){
    df[i]=as.character(i) + '-' + hits[i+1] - 1
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work how? You almost certainly don't need a for-loop since R is a vectorized language. Try using `diff(hits)` instead of `hits[i+1] - hits[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
info |> 
    group_by(percentage) |> 
    summarize(percentage = percentage[1], low = min(count)) |> 
    ungroup() |> 
    mutate(
      high = lead(low) - 1,
      high = ifelse(is.na(high), low, high),
      label = ifelse(low == high, low, paste0(low, "-", high))
    ) |>
    select(count = label, percentage)
```

That assumes that your original data is ordered by percentage. If it isn't you could order it first. A more general solution is indeed to use `cut()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to combine factor levels in R. I'll use a slightly larger sample than you provided:

```
set.seed(42)
count <- factor(sample.int(5, 20, replace=TRUE))
pct <- round(pct/sum(pct), 4) * 100
levels(count)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Now to combine the levels you just need one line:

```
levels(count) <- c("1-2", "1-2", "3-4", "3-4", "5")
levels(count)
# [1] "1-2" "3-4" "5"
```

Now create the summary data frame:

```
info <- data.frame(count, pct)    
Freq <- tapply(info$count, info$count, length)
Sum <- tapply(info$pct, info$count, sum)
info.df <- data.frame(Freq, Sum)
info.df
#     Freq   Sum
# 1-2   12 59.22
# 3-4    6 29.13
# 5      2 11.66
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is definitely helpful. Just as a follow-up question, what if I was not given explicit levels? How would I computer the levels such that I still get the desired output?

Comment: It is simpler if you use numeric values for `count`. Then you can use the `cut()` function (`?cut` for details), but you will have to decide what "desired output" is, e.g. each group about the same size, even intervals along the range, even intervals along the log of the range.